# FTP permissions differ from client to wordpress frontend

Tags: wordpress, apache, permissions, ftp

Running Centos 6, apache, MySQL and vsftpd. I am trying to upload a plugin to WordPress via its web frontend. I made a user on centos and vsftpd that would coordinate, added them to the same group (apache:apache) and but when I try and upload it I get the unpacking  the package, could not create directory error. I've change permissions from as the come to 777 (w/ -R) as well as checked that user groups are in sync. I've even gone and changed the user and group to make them the same as the login for the FTP. Here is the issue. If I login via a direct FTP client or over CLI, I don't have any issues and I checked that the users are the same, permissions, etc. I even added `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` to give it a go. All to no avail. I'd really like your thoughts. Hosted here so full root access is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - usually works:

```
# chown apache:apache {path_to_webroot} -R
# chmod 755 {path_to_webroot} -R
```